# How to select elements of a matrix given a vector with same number of columns?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have a matrix with 5 rows and 4 columns and a vector with 4 elements. I want to extract the 4 elements in the matrix where the corresponding vector value is the row index of that matrix element.

Here is my data:

```
mat1.data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
mat1 <- matrix(mat1.data,nrow=5,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
mat1

vec1<-c(4,2,5,1)
```

The output I am trying to get to is:

```
c(13,6,19,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can construct a `matrix` of row/column indexes to extract.  The column sequence can be `seq_len(ncol`

```
mat1[cbind(vec1, seq_len(ncol(mat1)))]
[1] 13  6 19  4
```

Or another option is to extract the `rows` and use `diag`

```
diag(mat1[vec1,])
[1] 13  6 19  4
```

Comment: Maybe shorter `mat1[cbind(vec1, seq_along(vec1))]` :P

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `mapply` + `asplit` (but not as efficient as [`diag` solution by  @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117374/12158757))

```
> mapply(`[[`, asplit(mat1, 2), vec1)
[1] 13  6 19  4
```

or `seq` + `nrow` + `ncol`

```
> mat1[(seq(ncol(mat1)) - 1) * nrow(mat1) + vec1]
[1] 13  6 19  4
```